# python error while using urllib module

Tags: python, module, urllib, urllib2

I was making python http banner grabber using `urllib` but it gives me an error.

I was not able it import `urllib2` (module not found error) so tried with with `urllib` instead.

Here's the code , what's wrong with it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib   
url=urllib.urlopen('www.bing.com')
print (url.info())
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Python 3; use [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) instead.

```
import urllib.request

url = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.bing.com')
print(url.info())
```

This is documented at the [top of the `urllib2` page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

> **Note**: The [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#module-urllib2) module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named `urllib.request` and `urllib.error`. The [`2to3`](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-to3) tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.